# Tutorial: TeXstudio add output path

Tags: texstudio

How can I add (in TeXstudio and Windows) an output directory for all those (un-)necessary files (I don't need 'em, LaTeX does: .aux, .glo, .idx, .log, ...) and automatically create this directory if it doesn't exist?

The pdf file can/should remain in the same directory as the main .tex file.

Comment: Don't do this: it is much better to leave the the output where it should be, in the current directory.

Comment: *I* don't like it that way. "Much better", how?

Comment: TeX's model for looking for input is all based around the current directory. If you use an output dir, you can get in to all sorts of issues when for example doing `epstopdf`, writing customised files and reading back, ...

Comment: Ok, I understand your concern.
To me, I only use the bascis, this works :-) Maybe when I run into trouble I'll think about your comment - Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Follow these few steps:

1. Create a batch file containing the command `mkdir _output`, which will create a folder named `_output` when run. Change `_output` to whatever name you like in both in this step and below. Save the batch file in a known and easy to access location.
2. Add the folder containing the batch file to TeXstudio: *Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Build* (you might need to enable advanced options), Commands ($PATH). See screenshot below.
3. Add your output folder name to *Log File* under *Additional Search Paths*.
4. Create a new *User Command* and enter the name of the batch file (not the full path) in the right-hand side of the row.
5. In *Meta Commands*, add this newly created user command to *Precompile*.
6. Add `--aux-directory=_output` to the end of PdfLaTeX command in *Commands*.

You're done! Enjoy a tidy tex-directory where all the "junk" is in the output directory. Only the .gz file remains in the tex-directory.

[image: TeXstudio Configuration]

I hope someone finds this useful...

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 16.04 lts, made it executable, added to path, still somehow it doesn't work. Says couldn't start build and view.

Comment: I didn't get the left box on the user command definition interface is the command I should use in precompile! I'm sorry